# When asked to load a lazy field, Hibernate loads all lazy fields

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading

I have a one2one relation between `Student` and `Address`. I want the `firstName` and `lastName` fields of `Student` to be lazy loaded. Also I want lazy for the `address` field.

These are my entity classes:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "student", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
  private Address address;

  @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @Column(name = "first_name")
  private String firstName;

  @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @Column(name = "last_name")
  private String lastName;

  // getters and setters
}
```

The Address class:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "addresses")
public class Address {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "s_id")
  private Student student;

  @Column
  private String street;

  // getters and setters
}
```

My test method looks like this ( the Java 8 lambda is just creating an entitymanager in back and executes all in transaction ):

```java
@Test
public void dummyTest() {
  JPA_UTILS.runInTransaction(e -> {
    Student s = e.find(Student.class, 150L);
    System.out.println("----------++++++++++++++-----------");
    s.getFirstName();
    System.out.println("----------++++++++++++++-----------");
  });
}
```

So here I am loading an existing student from the database, then fetch the lazy property `firstName` (mapped to the `first_name` column). The problem is that Hibernate doesn't load only `firstName` but also `lastName` and `address` fields:

```
just.hibernate.one2one.TestApp > dummyTest STANDARD_OUT
  Hibernate: 
    select
      student0_.id as id1_1_0_ 
    from students student0_ 
    where student0_.id=?
  ----------++++++++++++++-----------
  Hibernate: 
     /* sequential select just.hibernate.one2one.Student */
    select
      student_.first_name as first_na2_1_,
      student_.last_name as last_nam3_1_ 
    from students student_ 
    where student_.id=?
  Hibernate: 
    /* load just.hibernate.one2one.Address */
    select
      address0_.id as id1_0_1_,
      address0_.street as street2_0_1_,
      address0_.s_id as s_id3_0_1_,
      student1_.id as id1_1_0_ 
    from addresses address0_ 
    left outer join students student1_  on address0_.s_id=student1_.id 
    where address0_.s_id=?
  ----------++++++++++++++-----------
```

I don't want this behavior, I want to load only what I request. Can someone help me find the problem ?

Thanks

UPDATE1:

Instrumentation is done with maven, I'm posting only the relevant code (I've tried with gradle and the same results)

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>process-classes</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <tasks>
      <taskdef name="instrument" classname="org.hibernate.tool.instrument.javassist.InstrumentTask">
        <classpath>
          <path refid="maven.runtime.classpath" />
          <path refid="maven.plugin.classpath" />
        </classpath>
      </taskdef>
      <instrument verbose="false">
        <fileset dir="${project.build.outputDirectory}">
          <include name="**/*.class"></include>
        </fileset>
      </instrument>
    </tasks>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two essential resources to properly undestand this issue. Firstly, the lazy loading of properties is not the standard setting. See:

- [20.1.8. Using lazy property fetching](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#performance-fetching-lazyproperties)

> Hibernate supports the lazy fetching of individual properties. This optimization technique is also known as fetch groups. **Please note that this is mostly a marketing feature; optimizing row reads is much more important than optimization of column reads.** However, only loading some properties of a class could be useful in **extreme cases**.

Secondly, based on the above doc part, there is a detailed article about that:

- [NHibernate new feature: Lazy Properties](http://ayende.com/blog/4377/nhibernate-new-feature-lazy-properties)

*While this is related to NHibernate, the content is the same, because this feature comes from Hibernate.*

We can read there:

> What about multiple lazy properties? NHibernate support them, but you need to keep one thing in mind. **NHibernate will load all the entity’s lazy properties, not just the one that was immediately accessed**. By that same token, you can’t eagerly load just some of an entity’s lazy properties from HQL.

And again, we can understand that `lazy` setting for a property is not a standard setting. It is intended for some very specific cases, e.g.:

> This feature is mostly meant for unique circumstances, such as **Person.Image**, **Post.Text**, etc. As usual, be cautious in over using it.

**SUMMARY:** Lazy loading of properties *(ValueTypes/strings, not associations)* is there for special cases. It should help us to avoid loading some huge columns. BUT, once such a property is accessed, all others are loading as well

Comment: Simply putted, you can't :) . Thanks Radim, shame hibernate team!

Comment: In Hibernate 5.1+ you can use @LazyGroup to avoid loading all the entity's lazy properties.

Comment: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/HHH/issues/HHH-14546 was rejected with the comment (https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14546?focusedCommentId=108047) "... in order to obtain what you want you need to use the `@LazyGroup` annotation." So meanwhile, this IS technically possible according to the Hibernate team........

Answer (score 1):

With Hibernate you can load your columns lazily by using `@Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)` , but for this to work Hibernate requires bytecode instrumentation to intercept the attribute access request and issue the secondary select statement on demand.If using the Maven bytecode enhancement plugin, then `enableLazyInitialization` configuration property must be set to true as:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${hibernate.version}</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <configuration>
            <failOnError>true</failOnError>
            <enableLazyInitialization>true</enableLazyInitialization>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>enhance</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

This above plugin has its own disadvantages. SO instead if you need only certain columns you can write a named query requesting only those columns like

```
TypedQuery<ViewTemplate> query=getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT NEW com.abcd.test.Table(v.id,v.name,v.type) FROM ViewTemplate v where v.id>1",Table.class).getResultList();
```

And in your entity define a constructor with only these values

Answer (score 0):

For the one2one relation, I think following article explains it well:
 http://justonjava.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/lazy-one-to-one-and-one-to-many.html

Regarding the field lastName, this is a basic type field.
In Hibernate basic type fields always get queried together at once, regardess if you declare them to be loaded Lazy or not.

Comment: It's very fishy: I only ask to load s.getFirstName(); and I also get lastName & address. If I would have a BLOB instead of lastName, things would have been nasty. So I still think an annotations incantation & soup can do what I what :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you know about it so I'll explain; if you already know most of this I apologize for any offense.

By experience, we initially had lets say something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Student

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "student", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 private Address address;
```

Now observe the term FetchType.Eager. So in 'Page1' we lets say have a list of students. Then if you click on the students name it supposed to go to 'Page2'. So in 'Page2' you want the address of the student shown.

So in code, you wouldn't have to do two queries, if you do FetchType.Eager. All you will have to do is Student s = "Select s from Student where id = '1'";

Then you send this Object to 'Page2' and do System.out.println(s.getAddress());

Now this is only if FetchType is Eager. But if it is lazy. You need another query because the previous will error throwing a lazy exception. So then you will need to do like 
"Select a from Address a where a.student.id = ':id' in page 2 and then do System.out.println(resultOfSecondQuery);

Now this was my experience because we had EAGER first then it was changed to LAZY and errors start popping up in multiple places. Because we couldn't do s.getAddress() anymore.

In your test block it looks like you got all the Students and then printing out the firstname. Did you ever try printing out the address in your code? Did it print out or throw an error? I don't know what your fourth block is doing there. Did you write that or is that Hibernate doing something.

Documentations:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/lazyeager-loading-using
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-hibspec-singleassoc-fetching
http://howtoprogramwithjava.com/hibernate-eager-vs-lazy-fetch-type/

Also like it says in the documentation for jboss-hibernate, you don't need to lazy load simple properties like lastName. I know you probably just practicing but lastName is normally eager loaded anyway. Things like Address, however is different.