# How to know if lazy loading worked via hibernate mapping?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, hibernate-mapping

I have a Person object with 5 columns and i used following properties:

```
 property name="firstName" column="FirstName" type="string" lazy="false"
 property name="lastName" column="LastName" type="string" lazy="true"
 property name="city" column="City" type="string" lazy="true"
 property name="country" column="Country" type="string" lazy="true"
 property name="phone" column="Phone" type="string" lazy="true"
```

Now how do i find out if the object i get back using "From Person" contains only rows of data with the FIRSTNAME within it - assuming the other 4 are lazy loaded. I tried debugger but when i dive in i see all values has already been there... is there something missing? thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful :[When asked to load a lazy field, Hibernate loads all lazy fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25487148/when-asked-to-load-a-lazy-field-hibernate-loads-all-lazy-fields)

But, I thing it will not improve performance significantly, if it is a goal, unless you have hundreds of columns in the table. Leazy loading makes a big difference when featching collections.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the config `hibernate.show_sql=true` and view the output SQL.

Answer (score 0):

To find out if it's lazy loaded or not without checking the generated sqls you can simply close the session and then access the property.

However, you need further bytecode enhancement to enable this type of behavior. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html_single/#performance-fetching-lazyproperties

For instance, after enhancing the bytecode to enable lazy loading of horse (string property) inside Note and running.

```
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Note.class);
    List<Note> list1 = criteria.list();
    session.close();
    String horse = list1.get(0).getHorse();
```

I get

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: Unable to perform requested lazy initialization [stackoverflow.Note.horse] - no session and settings disallow loading outside the Session
    at org.hibernate.bytecode.enhance.spi.interceptor.Helper.throwLazyInitializationException(Helper.java:165)
```